# Inflated items are gone when device orientation changes

Tags: java, android

Hi i'm using eclipse for deveoping this android app. I'm inflating a layout using inflator and everything works fine.. I'm adding those inflated items one by one to another layout, so when the device's orientation is changed, all those inflated items are gone. The application seems like it has been restarted. But some values are still remaining.. Please help..

```
public void addNewItem() {
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_order_items, null);
    orderItemFrameView.add(item);       
    itemsLayout.addView(item);
    setAdditionalFonts(item);           
}

private void setAdditionalFonts(View view) {        
    TextView lblNameTak = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tak_itemNo); 
    AutoCompleteTextView txtNameTak = (AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tak_itemName);   
    ImageView barScan = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.barcode_scan);
    TextView lblRate = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tak_lblRate);
    TextView lblQty = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tak_lblQty);
    TextView lblTotal = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tak_lblTotal);
    TextView rate = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tak_Rate);
    EditText2 qty = (EditText2)view.findViewById(R.id.tak_Qty);
    TextView total = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tak_Total);
    qty.totTextView = total;
    qty.rateTextView = rate;        
    qty.orderTake = this;
    qty.index = orderItemFrameView.size() - 1;
    qty.sqlDb = SqlDb;
    qty.itemName = txtNameTak;
    setupBarcodeScan(barScan);

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ubuntu-l.ttf");
    Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/calibri.ttf");
    Typeface tf3 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ubu-r.ttf");        
    Typeface tf4 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/tahoma.ttf");
    lblNameTak.setTypeface(tf3);        
    txtNameTak.setTypeface(tf2);
    lblRate.setTypeface(tf2);   
    lblQty.setTypeface(tf2);    
    lblTotal.setTypeface(tf2);      
    lblNameTak.setText("Item " + (qty.index + 1));

    DbAdapterItem dbItem;
    TextAdapterItem txtItem;

    dbItem = new DbAdapterItem(this, SqlDb);                
    txtItem = new TextAdapterItem(dbItem,  this,  qty);
    txtNameTak.setAdapter(txtItem);     
    txtNameTak.setOnItemClickListener(txtItem);

    txtNameTak.requestFocus();
}
```

all these items created by addNewItem() are vanished...

here is the layout from which i'm inflating...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom ="22dp"

tools:context=".OrderItems" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"        
    android:background= "#888888"
    android:layout_height="98dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tak_itemNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2.7dp"
        android:text="Item 1"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#DDDDDD" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background= "#FFFFFF"     
        android:layout_height="75dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/tak_itemName"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:imeActionLabel="search"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.06"
                android:completionThreshold="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Item Name / Barcode"                  
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColorHint="#DDDDDD" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/barcode_scan"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="7dp"
                android:paddingRight="7dp"
                android:paddingTop="6dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"

                >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tak_lblRate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:textColor="#555555"
                android:textSize="10sp"            
                android:text="Rate" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tak_Rate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textSize="16sp"            
                android:text="0.00" />

            </FrameLayout>

             <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tak_lblQty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:textColor="#555555"
                android:textSize="10sp"            
                android:text="Qty" />

            <com.sayka.ordergadget.EditText2
                android:id="@+id/tak_Qty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"            
                android:text="0.0" />

            </FrameLayout>

              <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"

                >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tak_lblTotal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:textColor="#555555"
                android:textSize="10sp"            
                android:text="Total" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tak_Total"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textSize="16sp"            
                android:text="0.00" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

It's normal behaviour and you are correct. the activity is recreated from scratch on rotation.

If you want something to persist. store it during onSaveInstanceState in the provided bundle.

then during onCreate check to see if the bundle is null, if it isn't, pull your data out and add the view elements again.

Alternatively you can fudge it and state in the manifest that your activity will handle orientation/configuration changes.

Comment: All good except that last line. Manually handling orientation changes is a last resort and will still not prevent your Activity from being destroyed and recreated for other configuration change events other than orientation changes (e.g. inserting or removing a SIM card, changing languages, etc.).